# Does C++11 thread library call OS API to run multi-thread program?

Tags: linux, windows, multithreading, c++11, operating-system

As we all know,we can use C++  library write general multi-thread code across platform(no matter Linux or Windows),I wondered why c++11 make it simple,does it call OS API actually,or use some other technique?

Comment: On non-trivial, preemptive, multitasking OS like Windows, linux, no other technique is sensibly possible.  The OS manages all system resource allocation, and that includes memory, I/O and execution on a core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is just a language you used to express your ideas.

In the end, your binary still has to use operating system's features to perform anything that requires system-level access, such as manipulating the system scheduler (eg: creating a thread).

Details of what OS features your compiler and libraries use to support C++ language features can be found in their documentation. I guess most Linux envs use pthread under the hood for C++ threads, and windows ones use [win32 apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread).

If you use `gcc`, you can use `gcc -v` to get that information:

```
spectras@etherbee:~$ g++ -v
…
Thread model: posix
…
```

That means on my system it uses [posix threads](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does use the OS API. And you have to link the threading libraries when you use C++ threads.

In Linux/Unix pass `-pthread` to the compiler. In Visual Studio pick the MT runtime library.